# JSON undefined when accessing file attribute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have been trying to use an API from https://api.nomics.com/ and I cant seem to use the data inside the JSON object. I want to get the "price" value and display it in the console log but it keeps saying my variable is undefined please assist:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
request("https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=demo-26240835858194712a4f8cc0dc635c7a&ids=BTC&interval=1d&convert=USD&per-page=10&page=1", function(error, response, body) {

var data = JSON.parse(body);

var price = data.price;

console.log(data);

console.log(price);});});
```

The result I get is:

```
[ {
"id": "BTC",
"currency": "BTC",
"symbol": "BTC",
"name": "Bitcoin",
"logo_url": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nomics-api/static/images/currencies/btc.svg",
"status": "active",
"price": "10609.61844458",
"price_date": "2020-10-07T00:00:00Z",
"price_timestamp": "2020-10-07T08:12:00Z",
"circulating_supply": "18510093",
"max_supply": "21000000",
"market_cap": "196385024104",
"num_exchanges": "361",
"num_pairs": "38888",
"first_candle": "2011-08-18T00:00:00Z",
"first_trade": "2011-08-18T00:00:00Z",
"first_order_book": "2017-01-06T00:00:00Z",
"rank": "1",
"rank_delta": "0",
"high": "19337.69352527",
"high_timestamp": "2017-12-16T00:00:00Z",
"1d": {
  "volume": "16456552525.84",
  "price_change": "-148.44596940",
  "price_change_pct": "-0.0138",
  "volume_change": "1509811120.10",
  "volume_change_pct": "0.1010",
  "market_cap_change": "-2739282102.40",
  "market_cap_change_pct": "-0.0138"
} }]
```

var price is undefined. is it because of the "[]" that is surrounding the JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's because the request you are making return an array of objects, so you need to get the first element and on that get the price.
`var price = data[0].price;`